# create a section with name of subject and vote

Tags: ios, swift

in my application I have a viewController where I display the votes of some subjects of the school in a tableView.
I have grouped the votes with this method (static):

```
var sections = [
    Section(name: "Italiano",
            votes: [6, 7.5, 5, 10, 10, 10],
            expanded: false),
    Section(name: "Matematica",
            votes: [8, 7, 6, 7, 4, 10, 10],
            expanded: false),
    Section(name: "Fisica",
            votes: [9, 4.5, 6, 7, 10, 10],
            expanded: false),
    Section(name: "Sistemi",
            votes: [9, 6, 7, 8, 5.5, 10, 10],
            expanded: false)
]
```

Now I want to create `sections` dinamically, but I can't.
First I have to create every section with the name of a subject that I have in this array: `subjectsArray = ["Fisica","Italiano","Matematica","Sistemi"]`.
Then I take the votes from the DB and I have to assign them to the right section; a vote returns like this: 
`{1  -  Fisica  -  7  -  Orale  -  2017-08-04}
{2  -  Sistemi e Reti  -  6.75  -  Scritto  -  2017-08-01}
{3  -  Italiano  -  7  -  Scritto  -  2017-08-03}`
The first parameter is an ID, the second is the name of the subject, the third is the mark, the fourth is the type and the fifth is the date.
I only want to put the mark in the right section, so in the right subject
I hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

why you do not use Filters, filter object by name

```
 func getSubjects()->[Subject]
    {

        let italianoSection = listofData.filter { (subject : Subject) -> Bool in
            return subject.name == "Italiano"
        }


        return italianoSection

    }
```

Comment: I want to reply the Section that you see below with the subjects in the array and the votes that I take from the database